# Is loading UI in background thread okay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiviewcontroller

My app is presently made of a `TableViewController`, and a `ViewController`. When a `cell` in the `TableView` is selected, the `ViewController` is pushed, which is the main app. This View Controller previously loads all its `UIViews` in the **main thread**, which caused the screen to freeze as the code ran, often leading users to believe it has crashed. To prevent this issue, and improve the user experience, I have changed my code to the following overall format:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self initialiseApp];

}

- (void) initialiseApp {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Initialising views

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self getImageFromUrl:currentWallpaperURL]];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 100, screenWidth, (screenWidth/7)*4)];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

// etc etc for other views

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Add subviews to UI

        [[self view] addSubview:imageView];
    });
});

}
```

When app running in the simulator, this causes the `ViewController` to load as a blank screen, and later load the `UI` after some time. During loading, I would have some form of spinner, or text on the screen. I would therefore like clarification on this topic:

Is loading an app's `UI` when the `ViewController` is opened (or alternatively, when the app is launched) conventional? And if not, what is a better alternative to prevent having the app freeze for 10 seconds on launch?

Thanks.

Comment: The only part that should be done in the background is getting the image from the URL.

Comment: I usually use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to do this job for me. It is very easy to integrate and use.

Comment: No means no. Don't touch the interface in any way on anything but the main thread. No.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to experience issues when creating UI elements on background threads, so I would avoid this if possible ([Apple says the same](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW8)). In your situation, rather than loading the UI elements in the background, load the image in the background and then create the UI elements when the image has been loaded. As an example,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UIImage *image = [self getImageFromUrl:currentWallpaperURL];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Add subviews to UI
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 100, screenWidth, (screenWidth/7)*4)];
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [[self view] addSubview:imageView];
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know how, but doing this in fact made it load even faster. Thanks :)

Comment: Likely because your loading of it on a background thread caused issues and made it appear slower.